# USB Programming with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, usb, libusb

Is there anyway I can do USB programming in Qt? I am using Qt Creator 2.6 which is based on Qt version 5.0.0 and it is the latest Qt Creator which works with the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

I have the toy called "[Dreamcheeky Thunder Missile Launcher](http://www.dreamcheeky.com/thunder-missile-launcher)" and I need to program this USB based device.

I have tried LibUSB but it messed up everything. It even renamed the device port and I had to undo everything using *USBDview* software. But I guess I installed it incorrectly. I followed these [instructions](http://jaxov.com/2010/08/install-libusb-windows-7-vista-64-bit/). It is instructions for 64 bit, but I got 32 bit and since the instructions seems not to have big difference (instead the download file) I followed it. This is what I downloaded - `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0.zip`

Whatever the API you recommend it doesn't matter, even libusb, but please be kind enough to tell me how to install it properly.

My OS is windows 7 ultimate 32 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's another good instruction for **libusb** here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/

- **libusb**:

  - [libusb](http://libusb.org/)
  - [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) *(windows port - use this on windows!)*

If you stay on windows you can use

- **WinUSB**:

  - [WinUSB API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
  - [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
  - [Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For windows you can use both, but if your program has to be cross-platform you should use *libusb*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. In libusb, which item should I download?

Comment: Since you're running windows, please visit *libusb-win32* not *libusb*. There's a chaper *download* on the main page with a link to their download site - the latest version is on top.

Comment: Btw. the *installation instruction* chapter is next to *download*. it's a good step-by-step guide.

Comment: OK..Thanks. Do you know from where I can download WinUSB? Internet search results are messing with another software called "WinUSB Maker"

Comment: unfortunately not, but hopefully this helps you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: So to answer the question can he "do USB programming in Qt"...that's a no right? There's no USB API in Qt per se, you just use libusb directly?

Comment: Exactly :-) - but you can use *any* USB-API you get. libusb is just an example (but a very good one).

Answer (score 17):

ollo's answer is out of date. TL;DR is **use [libusb.info](http://libusb.info)**. A bit of explanation:

Originally there was libusb-0.1. Later they updated the API to libusb-1.0, but since libusb-0.1 had been around so long many projects didn't bother switching (kind of like Python 2/3). libusb-0.1 was not available for Windows, but libusb-1.0 is now available for all major platforms.

[libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) is a port of libusb-0.1 to Windows. You **shouldn't** use it for new code.

[libusb.org](http://libusb.org/) is the old website for libusb. The latest release is from 2012 and there are no Windows downloads.

[libusb.info](http://libusb.info/) is the current website for libusb. It contains libusb-1.0 downloads for all platforms and **you should use this for new code**.

To further confuse things, the sourceforge [libusb-win32 mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/libusb-win32-devel) is still used for libusb.info's development.