# How to setup LibUSB with Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, usb, libusb

I have installed LibUSB, but I still can't set it into [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator).

Following is my .pro file.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by Qt Creator 2013-05-08T20:27:36
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = USB
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp


include(3rdparty/qextserialport-1.2rc/src/qextserialport.pri)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/yohan/Documents/LibUSB/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/include
LIBS += C:/Users/yohan/Documents/LibUSB/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/lib/msvc/libusb.lib
```

This is my Qt Creator data:

[image]

Still, the IDE is not detecting libusb.h.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Anyway, are you sure that C:/Users/yohan/Documents/LibUSB/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/include/libusb.h exists? This is a serious question, paste it in a file browser, I've had this error a few times where I had just typed the wrong path. Just type `#include "C:/Users/yohan/Documents/LibUSB/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/include/libusb.h"` in your source file, and see if you get a compile error.

Comment: what do you mean by "the IDE is not detecting libusb.h". Does it mean the compiler can't find it? Or does the editor just mark it as missing? Check if you got possible subdirectories right. Here on linux, libusb.h is not in include/ directly, but in a subfolder (/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h)

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB Programming with Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450160/usb-programming-with-qt)