# Are there C++ examples available for libusb.h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, usb, libusb

I have been trying to install this crazy API called LibUSB. I downloaded the latest version `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0` and there is no .h file called `libUSB.h`. I got only `lusb0_usb.h` inside `C:\Users\yohan\Documents\LibUSB\libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0\include`

All the internet based examples are working with `libusb.h`. I need an example code/tutorial, since their webpage has nothing to help.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB Programming with Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450160/usb-programming-with-qt)

Comment: If you use lusb0_usb.h instead, is there any error or failure?

Comment: @ollo: Yes, the available examples fail. Specially, the last one in wartai's answer

Comment: Even the one in the example folder?

Comment: Did you follow installation steps in setup drivers?

Comment: @ollo: Yeah,  I am using C++. Those examples are C

Answer (score 3):

The win32 version of libusb uses the name `usb0` instead (maybe to avoid conflicts with "normal" libusb? There's some windows specific code required that will fail on any other system). so `lusb0_usb.h` is the header you have to include on windows. If you open that file you'll see anything you need in there.

**libUSB examples:**

- See [IV. Examples](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki/libusbwin32_documentation) - with `lusb0_usb.h` it should work the same.
- There are already some examples in the *libusb-win32* distribution - check **examples** directory in there. Some further are provided by *libusb*, you can browse them [online](http://libusb.org/browser/libusb/examples).
- [Introduction to using LibUSB-1.0](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/) (put please switch header).

If you realy need the `libUSB.h`, eg. for keeping compatibility, write your own one which actually includes the windows one:

*Example:*

```
#ifndef LIBUSB_H

#ifdef WIN32
# include <lusb0_usb.h>
#endif

#endif /* LIBUSB_H */
```

or simple:

```
#ifdef WIN32
# include <lusb0_usb.h>
#else
# include <libUSB.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. The examples in the last link work with libusb.h, simply changing the header didn't help :( Seems like all other functions also different